# GROUP CONCAT and ANCHOR URL issue

Tags: php, html, mysql

displaying group_concat values,when im displaying data in view....its displaying group_contat perfectly but not able to displayin URL of that particular list of group_contact list

note: its dynamic data displaying using foreach statement.

view:

```
<?php foreach ($home_cat as $homecat ) { ?>

     <div class="col-md-4">

            <h3 class="text-center" style="border: 1px solid red"><?php echo $homecat['catagories']?></h3>
            <div class="row">
                <img style="width: 350px; height: 250px"
                    src="<?php echo base_url();?>inc/img/<?php  echo $homecat['catagory_image']?>">
                <h6><?php

        $listdata = explode ( ',', $homecat ['cat_data'] );
        foreach ( $listdata as $list_data ) {
            echo '<a href="#">' . $list_data . '</a></br>';
        }
        ?>

    </h6>
            </div>
        </div>

       <?php  }  ?>
```

Now i want to display my database url in place of "#".

model

```
$this->db->select('a.id,a.catagories,b.catagory_image,b.catagory_url as url,GROUP_CONCAT(b.catagory_title) as cat_data');
    $this->db->from('catagory as a');
    $this->db->join('home_page as b','a.id = b.c_id','inner');
    $this->db->group_by('a.id');



     $query = $this->db->get();
     return $query->result_array();
```

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJIaI.png)

Comment: show the related code

Comment: sir i added the code ...please once check

Comment: your code fragment is not complete, show your mysql query call part as well. and describe expected result you are looking for.

Comment: I have posted an answer with soome suggestion for debug

Comment: do you have your project url open to public? can you post the link to the page?

Comment: no working on Localhost...

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you path is right

```
 src="<?php echo base_url();?>inc/img/<?php  echo $homecat['catagory_image']?>">
```

eventually try for debugging with

```
$my_url = base_url() . 'inc/img/' . $homecat['catagory_image'];
var_dum($my_url) ;
```

could be you have missing a `/`  eg: `'/inc/img/'`   or your `$homecat['catagory_image']` don't contain proper value

Answer (score 0):

I fI got your goal correctly : *Now i want to display my database url in place of "#".*

You should just change your:

```
echo '<a href="#">' . $list_data . '</a></br>';
```

to

```
echo '<a href="'. $homecat ['url'].'">' . $list_data . '</a></br>';
```

Comment: sir i had URL Column in DATABASE for data particular $list_data.....Now i  want insert in href="<here>".....Hope u understand.....facing problem since 3 hours

Comment: i tired to put id insteaded of url.....only first id is loading ..... i think we have to use foreach statement...but how....help me sir

Comment: I can not help you since you did not provide neither enough code fragment nor source data, nor expected result

Comment: sir i'm displaying data by using GROUP_CONCAT...,Just i want to put that concat data ID in href="" tag.......wen i tired to place,its placing only parent id not GROUP DATA id in href=""

hope it helps me